# Can you link a Python script to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

My aim is to create a recommendation app for Android which communicates with a script from a server to perform the Machine Learning parts and to generate recommendations for the current user. My original idea was to use Tensorflow but I am wondering if I could also write a Python script which can be called as a REST API? Would the data be best passed in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Python Flask API and sent a POST Request to it. From that, you can use the data passed to run your ML parts on that data. However, you will need to find a way to run those ML parts after you pass your data to your Flask API. To get started, I would watch a youtube tutorial on how to make and use a Flask API. It is not terribly difficult to get up and started.